# gather element that share infomation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to gather element that share something in common.

Example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'C1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'R', 'X'], 'C2': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'S', 'Y']})
    C1  C2
0   A   B
1   B   C
2   C   D
3   D   E
4   R   S
5   X   Y
```

and This is what I'm looking for:

```
    Groups
0   [A, B, C, D, E]
1   [R, S]
2   [X, Y]
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`networkx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) here.

Approaching your data as a graph is a reliable way to ensure grouping all values together.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='C1', target='C2')

out = pd.DataFrame({'Groups': map(sorted, nx.connected_components(G))})
```

output:

```
            Groups
0  [A, B, C, D, E]
1           [R, S]
2           [X, Y]
```

Your graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly ^^. 
Do you have any idea if I want to do it without networkx (the reason is ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to write a function with a node clustering algorithm (something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251308/python-connected-components-edges-list), **untested**) ;)